# send file to api request from python to react-native javascript conversion code

Tags: javascript, python, api, file, react-native

I use the api of a 3rd party software called plate recognizer that can be seen [here](https://platerecognizer.com/api-documentation/?python#authentication) I tried their python sample code and it works properly, but when I tried it using my javascript code, their api response different value means my javascript code is not equivalent to their python code that their provided to me that is working, the question is how can I make my code exactly a same function as the python code that I created?

This is the python code that I run and gives me a successful response with the expected output.

```
# pip install requests
import requests
from pprint import pprint

with open('./sampleCar3.jpg', 'rb') as fp:
    response = requests.post(
        'https://platerecognizer.com/api/plate-reader/',
        files=dict(upload=fp),
        headers={'Authorization': 'Token API_TOKEN'})
pprint(response.json())
```

And this is the code that I tried on javascript that logs an error output

```
placeRecognizerPostRequest(imgSrc) {
        // imgSrc value = ./sampleCar3.jpg
        const body = new FormData();
        body.append("upload", imgSrc);

        fetch("https://platerecognizer.com/api/plate-reader/", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Token API_TOKEN",
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            body: body
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

I want a success output response of their api, it's successful in my python code, but it's giving me a failed json response that is not expected.

PS. the file path of both image in both codes are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have uploaded images to a server I have constructed the `FormData` in the following way.

```
let file = {
    name: 'myimage.jpg',
    uri: 'path/to/the/image/myimage.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpg'
 };

 let body = new FormData();
 body.append('upload', file);
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation now includes an example of how to [use the API in Javascript](https://platerecognizer.com/api-documentation/?javascript#license-plate-recognition).